# Toast on click navigate to another page

Tags: angular, toast, ionic4

l have this [ion toast](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/toast#methods) . I want to implement the following. when the user clicks on toast notification, the event click will navigate to a specific page. I did try the code below, but it doesn't work.

code

```
const toast = await this.toastController.create({
        message: 'click on details ',
        color:'danger',
        duration:7000,
        showCloseButton:true

      });


      toast.onDidDismiss().then(()=>{
        this.nav.navigateForward('/home')
      })
       toast.present();
```

Comment: Why don't you use click property provided with toast controller

Comment: i mean like this : ```Toast.create({
    message: 'You have a new message!',
    duration: 2000,
    click: () => {
        this.nav.push(ReadMessagePage);
    }
}); ```

Comment: click is not exist in Toast controller

Comment: Sorry , Good luck!